# How to avoid mypy complaints when inheriting from a built-in collection type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Running `mypy` on code like this

```py
class MySpecialList(list):
   # funky extra functionality
```

gives me

```
my_file.py:42: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "list"  [type-arg]
```

I can avoid this by not inheriting from `list` at all or ignoring this error.

But how *should* I deal with this? Isn't this a bug in mypy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of using `--disallow-any-generics` (which is implied by `--strict`), as `list` is equivalent to `list[Any]`. You can fix it by making `MySpecialist` explicitly generic via a type variable.

```
from typing import TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')


class MySpecialList(list[T]):
    ...
```